# ¿Qué métodos se ejecutan al cerrar una aplicación?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una aplicación la cual al iniciar ejecuta un servicio de servidor y le proporciona unos datos tales como la ip y el puerto para la conexión, el problema viene al cerrar y abrir la aplicación sospecho que esos datos se quedan almacenados y no me permite volver a conectarme al servidor.
Quería saber que métodos son los mas habituales o que se ejecutan al cerrar una aplicación de cualquier forma ( pulsando el botón atrás o destruyéndola directamente ) para poder volver a poner la información de la conexión a null cuando se cierra mi aplicación.

Un saludo.

Comment: [Ciclo de vida de una actividad en android](https://stories.devacademy.la/android-ciclo-de-vida-de-un-activity-b2a68c506961)

Comment: http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android/37-unidad-6-multimedia-y-ciclo-de-vida/158-ciclo-de-vida-de-una-actividad

Comment: onPause onStop y onDestroy revisalo en el ciclo de vida de la Activity busca esta información en el sitio, te sugiero agregues tu código sería bueno para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido al sito J. Burrueco... !!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta agregando lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos.